# Jenkins pipeline job using variables

Tags: jenkins

I have to call two jobs thru pipleline.

1st job is build job , it has to be paramaterized to be able to select the branch/trunk and also be able to specify some variables like skip test, select environment. Whats the best approach?

I have tried with parametrised job , it gives drop down selections to select the desired branch or trunk. But I'm clueless where I can include variables to select the profile, basically to get the below command working

```
mvn -P ${profiles} -DskipTests=false  clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that you tried parametrized job to select the trunk. You can create another parameter named *profiles* and your command should work.

Comment: Can you share your configuration details?